# ValueError: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 in Python

Tags: python

It says ValueError. I've tried using int('') as well. Didn't work.

```
first = []
a=int(input());

for i in range(0,a):
    ele = int(input());
    first.append(ele);

second = first[::-1];

th = [x + y for x, y in zip(first, second)];
print(th);
```

Comment: In python you don't need `;` and you can only convert strings to int with only numbers in it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask]. What's your question? Please [edit] to clarify. If you want debugging help, you need to provide a [mre], but atm you're missing the input.

Comment: related, see [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response). And also read about the [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) constructor

Comment: It works fine for me as long as I introduce numbers. If I introduce characters it throws the error you say, which is normal. Just remove `;` you don't need it in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=int#int), the class constructor for int is as follows.

```py
class int(x, base=10)
```

So a base of 10 is assumed (I guess because a decimal number system is the most prevalent) unless and otherwise you state something else.

So what should be x?

Again as per the docs.

> If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string, bytes, or bytearray instance representing an integer literal in radix base.

So the x should be an integer literal of that base. If you supply an alphabet say 'A' for int like below, the 'A' can not be represented as an integer using a decimal number system. Trying to do the below ..

```py
Num = int('A')
print(Num)
```

will get you an error ...

```sh
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'A'
```

However, if your number system (base) is hexadecimal then you can say base=16 and it will faithfully convert 'A' it into an integer. So the below ...

```py
Num = int('A', base=16)
print(Num)
```

gives ..

```sh
10
```

**So please check what is your number system (base) is and see if the string (that you are trying to convert to an integer) makes sense for that particular number system.**